# Magento 2 - Rearange invoice items

Tags: magento2, invoice

I want to rearange those "steps" inside all emails and pdf-printouts.

Is there any clear way to do that ?

[image]

Also, if possible, i want to change the "Steuer" to display another text. Is that also possible in a fast and Clear way ?